# About convergence of $(T_nR_n)$ when $(T_n),(R_n) \subset B(X)$

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, operator-theory

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $(T_n),(R_n) \subset B(X)$.

(a) Prove that if $(T_n)$ converges strongly and $(R_n)$ converges strongly or uniformly, then $(T_nR_n)$ converges strongly
(b) Prove that if $(T_n)$ converges weakly and $(R_n)$ converges strongly or uniformly, then $(T_nR_n)$ converges weakly

This probably is quite straightforward but somehow I can't get it right. As for the part a) I think I should show that
$||T_nR_nx - TRx|| \rightarrow 0$.
This however, is causing me some problems. I have tried several different things but none of them has worked. As for part b) I think I should just use the definition of weak convergence in the same manner as in part a).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two hints for (a):

1. Write $T_n R_n x - TRx = T_n R_n x - T_n R x + T_n R x - TRx$.  Think about the triangle inequality.  (This is a useful technique whenever you have a situation where two different things are converging: try to split it up so you can handle one at a time.)
2. By the uniform boundedness principle, $\sup_n \|T_n\| < \infty$.

Question (b) can be solved with similar tricks.

Comment: Ok thank you, that helped. Actually my first idea was to try that but I had some problems with it. By doing that I get two terms:  $||T_nR_nx - TRx|| \leq ||T_n||||R_nx-Rx|| + ||(T_n-T)Rx||$. I get why the first one goes to zero but the second term is causing me some confusion. Seeing as $(T_n)$ converges strongly I don't think I can just say that $||T_n - T|| \rightarrow 0$. Or have I made a mistake somewhere?

Comment: @user4784: you've got it! $T_n \to T$ strongly means $T_n y \to Ty$ for any $y$. Apply with $y=Rx$ :-)

Comment: Oh yes of course, funny that I did not see that myself. Anyway, thanks alot for help, it makes perfect sense now.